# How can I get the default User then Machine cascading environment variable preference behavior one would expect in c#?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up the same environment variable such that there is a system default and individual users can choose a different option if they so choose. To my knowledge, this is just supposed to work, if I have the same environment variable in two place, the user variable is given preference. However in C# when I get an environment variable, I must choose either Machine or User caches.

I suppose I can code it to just check user and if it's null then go to machine, but this seems like an unfortunate roundabout way to do something that I thought the OS was supposed to take care of for me -- What is the proper way to offload this responsibility to the OS?

Below is what I suppose I could use to get the environment variable, but it seems tedious when I believe the OS should handle it.

```
var FooVariable = 
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Foo", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) ??
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Foo", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Comment: " I must choose either Machine or User caches." - can you show us what you mean?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, I totally forgot. I've added an example

Comment: If you omit `EnvironmentVariableTarget`, it will look them up in the user environment, then in the machine environment...

Comment: You can only get the variable that are set.  Open cmd.exe >Set which will give a list of variables.

Comment: @CodeCaster According to the [documentation for that overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_), omitting the target is the same calling with `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process`... that is, just the variables for that process. It's possible the process would inherit this behavior, but that's not clearly indicated in the documentation.